# How can I fix the spacing between text and numbering in newntheorema

Tags: spacing, examples, newtheorem

I'm using a newtheorem to create the numbering of an example, but the spacing has been very different from one number to another.

I've already tried using `\hspace` after Ex. (and before numbering). I've tried using a minipage to see if I can put the numbering in the style of Ex.1:, but without success.

The fact that I wanted everything to be like this standard Ex.1: (so no space)

See the photo below of my screen.

My code is:

```
\newtheoremstyle{exemplo} {\topsep}   % above space
  {\topsep}   % below space
  {}  % body font
  {0pt}       % indent
  {\bfseries} % head font
  {:}         % head punctuation
  {0.2cm} % HEADSPACE
  {}          % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC

\theoremstyle{exemplo}
\newcounter{exemplo}

\setcounter{exemplo}{0} % Just for demonstration

\newtheorem{exem}[exemplo]{Ex. \hspace {-0.32cm}}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Use the final argument to `\newtheoremstyle` to specify that the header has to be set in a box, so that the spaces in it are frozen.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{exemplo}
  {\topsep}   % above space
  {\topsep}   % below space
  {}          % body font
  {0pt}       % indent
  {\bfseries} % head font
  {:}         % head punctuation
  {0.2cm}     % HEADSPACE
  {\mbox{\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2}\thmnote{ #3}}} % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC

\theoremstyle{exemplo}
\newcounter{exemplo}

\setcounter{exemplo}{0} % Just for demonstration

\newtheorem{exem}[exemplo]{Ex.\@}

\begin{document}

\begin{exem}
Calcule usando o algoritmo da decomposição calcule
\end{exem}

\begin{exem}
Numa sala de aula tem 18 meninas e 13 meninos,
quantos aiunos tem messa sala?
\end{exem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for comparison, with an empty final argument we'd get

[image]

Thus you see that the `\mbox` really fixes the issue. Note also `\@` in order to make the period not sentence ending. Maybe your setting includes `\frenchspacing`, but it's best to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `amsthm`, just a normal space is placed after the theorem name, and that space will expand along with other spaces as needed to achieve full justification. Since in different contexts, that amount of space may vary, the size of the space fluctuates.

The best way around this I can come up with would be to redefine the command `\thmhead` so that it uses `\mbox{\ }` instead of a regular space, which won't expand in this way. You might be able to do this by putting this near the end of your premable.

```
\makeatletter
\def\thmhead#1#2#3{%
  \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{\mbox{\ }}\@upn{#2}}%
  \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont(#3)}}}
\makeatother
```

Or if you really want no space at all between "Ex." and the number:

```
\makeatletter
\def\thmhead#1#2#3{%
  \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{}\@upn{#2}}%
  \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont(#3)}}}
\makeatother
```

But I have a feeling there may be better ways.

Comment: Rather than an `\mbox`, you might consider a `\thinspace`.  The period after "Ex." already has a rather substantial visual space, and the usual headword for `amsthm` is not an abbreviation.  Just a regular word space would be okay, but unless `\frenchspacing` is in effect, an abbreviation will trigger an end-of-sentence space, which is definitely inappropriate.